# Meteor/Apollo: Set Up Redis Pubsub for Production?

Tags: meteor, redis, graphql, publish-subscribe, apollo

I'm working on getting Redis Pubsub working in my Meteor app hosted on Galaxy.

The [Redis Pubsub docs](https://github.com/davidyaha/graphql-redis-subscriptions) say to initialize it this way:

```
import { RedisPubSub } from 'graphql-redis-subscriptions';
import * as Redis from 'ioredis';

const options = {
  host: REDIS_DOMAIN_NAME,
  port: PORT_NUMBER,
  retry_strategy: options => {
    // reconnect after
    return Math.max(options.attempt * 100, 3000);
  }
};

const pubsub = new RedisPubSub({
  ...,
  publisher: new Redis(options),
  subscriber: new Redis(options)
});
```

When I run:

```
const options = {
    host: Meteor.isProduction ? 'www.myDomain.com': 'dev.myDomain.com',
    port: Meteor.isProduction ? 443 : 3000,
    retry_strategy: options => {
        // reconnect after
        return Math.max(options.attempt * 100, 3000);
    }
};

const pubsub = new RedisPubSub({
    publisher: new Redis(options),
    subscriber: new Redis(options)
});
```

...I get this console log error on my dev system:

> TypeError: Redis is not a constructor

I also tried it like this:

```
const pubsub = new RedisPubSub({
    publisher: new Redis.createClient(options),
    subscriber: new Redis.createClient(options)
});
```

...and got the console log error on my dev system:

> [ioredis] Unhandled error event: MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20).

What is the correct way to initialize Redis Pubsub for production?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I **think** I see what this is. I need to install Redis separately on the server, and Galaxy doesn't yet support that.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think I get it. Pubsub really needs to be running on a database server.

There’s no need for Galaxy to support that because Galaxy wants you to run your database on another host even if the database is Mongo.

Since my database is in postgres,  I added in GraphQLCollege:graphql-postgres-subscriptions, set up the options for it as described on https://www.graphql.college/graphql-subscriptions-with-react-node-apollo-and-postgres/, and my pubsub started working on Galaxy right away.  Solved! (edited)